# How to generate flat axi-symmetric polyhedral faces tiling to a parabolic reflector surface?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, polyhedra, reflection

How can I generate flat polar/axi-symmetric polyhedral faces tiling to a parabolic reflector surface?

Cheers.

Comment: You want a cut  polyhedral surface that brings paraxial rays to focus by reflection?

Comment: That sounds exactly correct. Do you know how I could do it, or could you point me in the direction of information on how to do it?

Comment: Your question may be edited somewhat like:" How to generate  flat polar / axi-symmetric polyhedral faces tiling  to a parabolic reflector surface ?" etc.

Comment: @Narasimham That sounds perfect. I've edited the question. Thanks : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular polyhedra cut from a sphere and parabolic reflector meridian are two *different* things.

In order to define an axisymmetric reticulated net you need to define what geometric parameter like length/angle you want to hold constant. For constant rhombus side size say 1/10th of focal length. In the image parallels can be ignored, arc is shown one continuous line instead of several connected edges.

[image: Parabolic Dish Tesellated]

Comment: Wow. How did you generate that shape? That's what I want to be able to do.

Comment: Continued: Sorry, I didn't really know what a cut polyhedra is. I want to create a parabolic reflector from a small set of polygons. That's what I was trying to ask about. What's the simplest way to create a parabolic reflector from flat polygons? Should I ask it as another question? Not sure what to do. My bad question already got down voted, oops : ) Thanks for what you've done already by the way. That rhombus reflector is nice.

Comment: Do not worry about down-votings. Try to re-edit. Cut polyhedron was not needed. I expressed that way because a doubly curved surface generates such edges when cut by planes that are changed after each cut, I imagined  its formation like with precious stones cutting/grinding.

Comment: Forgot it altogether!  image updated.